# How to extend GameMaker Studio's IDE editor, like in Unity?

Tags: game-maker, editors

Unity allows you to create custom inspectors, [custom editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.2/Documentation/Manual/ExtendingTheEditor.html) windows and custom property drawers.

Is there a counterpart of this in GameMaker Studio 2.x or isn't it possible yet?

Comment: You may want to explain a bit further what are those Unity features you are looking for, because someone who knows Unity may not know Game Maker Studio and vice versa, making it difficult to find someone who can answer this question.

Comment: I don't know if this is what your looking for, but if you have a window open in you can click and drag the top of it to seperate it from the main window.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this was asked, but hopefully, this can be helpful to anyone learning.

In Gamemaker you cannot currently do this, at least not in the way where a window is integrated within a tab or window in the engine itself. However, the way one would go about doing this in a practical sense within GM look to the Room Editor. In short, to make extra development tools you make them within the executable itself in an "editor" room. So once executed the room is its own sub-engine space where you can have custom object-makers and room-builders that optimize certain things and overall fits your taste/needs.

To harvest this data from the executable one needs to keep in mind exporting to specific Gamemaker file types and the like. This part may be a little tricky, but once figured out you basically have everything one needs to have functioning extra tools with whatever UI you'd like. Just remember to maybe not include the "maker" files in the actual game exe when you're done.